# What causes this git push error inside of visual studio 2017 v15.5.6?

Tags: git, visual-studio

Trying to push my GIT commit inside of Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.6 and running into strange error when pushing commit from inside visual studio:

`Error encountered while fetching: Git failed with a fatal error.
HttpRequestException encountered.
   An error occurred while sending the request.
cannot spawn askpass: No such file or directory
could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled`

What might cause this error?  How do you troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Updated to Visual Studio 15.5.7 and can now push my commit without error.